# How to change a specific value in data-i18n, without using the language files

Tags: javascript, i18next

I am embedding a foreign system that uses i18n into my website. I have no control over the source of language files, and my language isn't one of the available languages there.

But I do have access to `JavaScript/jQuery`, so I thought I'd change a few of the headers, to give the interface a more localized feel. Not a full translation, just a few of the more prominent values.

Is there a way to select specific i18n elements, and change their value using `JavaScript/jQuery?`

This is the syntax of the elements I want to change:

`<div class="className" data-i18n="some.idententifier">English Value</div>`

*edit:*

Some more research got me to a point where I managed to change content of divs, but it only works when the identifier is one word, no dots. 
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/einavatar/50wnqrym/1/

But **all** the identifiers on the interface I'm using make use of the dot syntax. How can I hook on to those then?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, @Cerbrus. I should have mentioned I have no past experience with i18n, and I spent the morning Googling, but I only found explanations on how to build the original html to suit i18n, or how to change the language for the whole page. But here the html is already written, and I cannot change the language. So I'm just looking for a selector to hook onto specific data-i18n identifier - I don't even know if it's a feature of i18n or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your jsfiddle you have `doesnt.work` as a single key.  Split that up into `doesnt: { work: "different value" }` and you should find it works (ironically unless you change doesnt to does).

Comment: in that fiddle you typod 'doesnt' in the markup, fix that and it will work

Comment: Well spotted! Now it works. And I also got it to work where there are 4 or 5 levels down the dot hierarchy :-) but when I try to implement the same syntax in the real interface, not the fiddle, what happens is that all text values are either deleted, or show as their identifiers instead of the text. Is there a way to tell the application to default back to English wherever I didn't specifically defined something else?

Comment: If you can find the network resource that provides the english translation (e.g. as a JSON file) you can fetch it with an XHR and add it into the object alongside 'dev', although 'dev' will be preferred over english so I'd call 'dev' the actual language you want to use instead of 'dev'.  Otherwise I'm not sure if it's possible to configure it not to do any translation if the translation is missing, but maybe it is.